# Notación de slicing en Python

Tags: python

Buen día, tengo problemas para entender la notación de slicing de 3 argumentos con índices negativos.

```py
# [inicio:parada:paso]
# Si se omite <inicio>, se utiliza 0.
# Si se omite <final>, se utiliza len(arr).
# Si se omite <paso>, se utiliza 1.
# Aclaración: Al igual que en la función range() Python no incluye el índice final.
# Con paso positivo se revisan los índices hacia la derecha.
# Con paso negativo se revisan los índices hacia la izquierda.
nums = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
print(nums[1::-1]) # Primer caso
print(nums[:-3:-1]) # Segundo caso
print(nums[-3::-1]) # Tercer caso
```

¿En el primer caso no tendría que recuperar todos los números desde el índice -1 hasta el índice 1? A la salida devuelve: [20, 10]
¿En el segundo caso no tendría que recuperar todos los números desde el índice -3 (sin incluirlo) hasta el inicio? A la salida devuelve: [90, 80]
¿En el tercer caso no tendría que recuperar todos los números de desde el final hasta el índice -3? A la salida devuelve: [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]

De antemano, agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes entender el slicing de la siguiente manera **lista[ inicio : fin(exclusivo) : avance ]**

Exclusivo significa que no toma en cuenta esa posicion en el resultado. En escencia lo excluye del resultado.

```
nums[1::-1]
```

Significa: inicia en la posicion 1 (valor 20), hasta que termine de recorrer la lista, avanza 1 en forma inversa. Va de la posicion 1, hasta terminar, avanzando 1 en forma inversa, posiciones 1, 0. [20, 10], de atras hacia adelante.

```
nums[:-3:-1]
```

Significa: inicia desde el principio, hasta la posicion -3, es decir, la posicion antepenultima(sin incluir) (valor 70), de atras hacia adelante, [90, 80]

```
nums[-3::-1]
```

Significa: inicia en la posicion -3 valor(70), hasta el final, en orden inverzo. [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]

Por ultimo puedes hacer que avance cada dos posiciones, por ejemplo:

```
print(nums[::2])
```

Significa inicia desde el inicio, termina al final de la lista, avanza dos. Inicia en posicion 0 (valor 10), la siguiente posicion es 0 + 2 = 2 (valor 30), la siguente posicion sera 2 + 2 = 4 (valor 50) y asi sigue hasta [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]